# How to merge Text, Sphere and Box Geometry?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I am trying to merge text, sphere and box geometry so I am able to change position all with just one set position. The condition is that I  have to use BufferGeometry. Everything worked fine when I merged the sphere and box but I got error in merge text geometry.

It say `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined at X.BufferGeometry.fromGeometry`

```
let modelGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
const globalMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
const head = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 16);
const body = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 16);
const textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry("text ID", {
  font: "monaco",
  size: 1,
  height: 0,
  curveSegments: 3,
});

textGeometry.computeBoundingBox();
textGeometry.mergeVertices();

const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });

const workerId = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

const headMesh = new THREE.Mesh(head, globalMaterial);
const bodyMesh = new THREE.Mesh(body, globalMaterial);
headMesh.matrix.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 3));
bodyMesh.matrix.scale(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 4));
modelGeometry.merge(headMesh.geometry, headMesh.matrix);
modelGeometry.merge(bodyMesh.geometry, bodyMesh.matrix);
modelGeometry.merge(workerId.geometry, workerId.matrix);

const bufGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(modelGeometry);

this.human = new THREE.Mesh(bufGeometry, globalMaterial);
this.modelBuilder.addMesh(this.human);
```

Comment: What revision of Three.js do you use? Since r125, `THREE.Geometry()` was moved from the core of framework. Now all geometries are buffer geometries. To merget them you have to use `BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries( _array_ );`

Comment: I use r71 ThreeJS version which is a lib from Autodesk Forge.

Answer (score 1):

Reference to this [discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/merging-text-geometry-and-sphere-geometry/29470/6) something missing in Text Geometry. Need to add computeVertexNormals();

```
modelGeometry.merge(headMesh.geometry, headMesh.matrix);
modelGeometry.merge(bodyMesh.geometry, bodyMesh.matrix);
modelGeometry.merge(humanIdMesh.geometry, humanIdMesh.matrix);
modelGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
const humanModel = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(modelGeometry);
```